# Copying multiple directories into multiple destination directories

Tags: bash, for-loop, directory, cp

In my base directory there are three directories that I wish to copy into the other directories in my base. It looks like this:

```
base
|-Dir1
|-Dir2
|-Dir3
|-Dir4
.
.
.
|-foo
|-bar
|-mar
```

I wish to copy those three so have the following structure:

```
base
|-Dir1
    |-foo
    |-bar
    |-mar
|-Dir2
    |-foo
    |-bar
    |-mar
|-Dir3
    |-foo
    |-bar
    |-mar
|-Dir4
    |-foo
    |-bar
    |-mar
.
.
.
|-foo
|-bar
|-mar
```

I have more than the four directories, hence why I am trying to create a method to copy them programmatically. I have attempted the following to no avail:

```
cp -avr ./{foo,bar,mar}/ ./Dir{1,2,3,4}
for file in `find . -type d -name ./Dir*/`; do (cd "$file" && cp ../{foo,bar,mar}/ .); done
```

After having attempted the initial `cp` solutions I realised that it only worked for a single destination, so I attempted a couple of loops but I could not get any of them to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there.
Would you please try the following:

```
for d in base/Dir*; do
    cp -av base/{foo,bar,mar} "$d"
done
```

Note that `` for file in `find ..` `` may break if the pathname contains whitespace, tab or newline. It will be robust to use globbing with `Dir*`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is the point of using `find` here? OP shows that source and destination folders are atthe same level

Comment: I had read in some other questions regarding similar matters that `find` is useful for listing specific files in a directory, acting as a filter.

Comment: @oguzismail you're right. I've simplified my answer with globbing.

Comment: @protein_fashion thank you for trying my code. Both `find` and `for with file globbing` will work. Please avoid to say ``for file in `find ..` `` anyway.