# Copying the same directory from multiple parent directories to a multiple destinations

Tags: powershell, directory, tree, windows-10, copy

What I want to do is copy a directory that exists in multiple parent directories, to a destination while preserving the \Parent\child structure. The source directories are versioned software releases, and the directory that I want contains hot-fixes for each of those versions.

Source directory structure

```
\Releases\app_26.6.1.123\Patch\
\Releases\app_26.6.2.456\Patch\
etc etc
```

The last two numbers change, but the format is always #.## or #.###, with the first # incrementing from 1 to 7.

And what I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
copy \Release\app_26.6.[1-7].*\Patch\ to C:\Temp\eureka\app_26.6.[1-7].*\Patch\
```

I think that I'll have to use a for loop iteration, but my brain is hurting trying to think of a way to do this in powershell; and that's why I'm here.

This post is pretty close to what I want to do, but wrong platform:
[Copying multiple directories into multiple destination directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59063075/copying-multiple-directories-into-multiple-destination-directories)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have multiple destinations per source patch? Try something like this where you wildcard up the version number in the name:

```
Foreach ($src in (Get-Item "\Releases\app_*\Patch")) {

  # Split off the last version number on the parent folder
  $baseVersion = ($src.parent.name -split '\.')[0..2] -join '.'

  # Get each destination folder using * wildcard
  $destinations = Get-Item "c:/Temp/eureka/$baseVersion*/"

  # Copy folders
  Foreach ($dst in $destinations) {
    Copy-Item $src.FullName $dst.FullName -Recurse 
  }

}
```

This should create the following source and destination structure:

```
# src
\Releases\app_26.6.1.123\Patch\1
\Releases\app_26.6.2.456\Patch\2

# dst
c:/Temp/eureka/app_26.6.1.100/Patch/1
c:/Temp/eureka/app_26.6.1.200/Patch/1

c:/Temp/eureka/app_26.6.2.300/Patch/2
c:/Temp/eureka/app_26.6.2.400/Patch/2
```

If you don't want a wildcard but specifically need `[1-7]`, you can use regex:

```sh
$destinations = Get-Item "c:/Temp/eureka/*/" |
  Where Name -match "$baseversion.[1-7]"
```

Comment: I would've never figured that out on my own, at least not in a reasonable amount of time. Much appreciated.